# Android Gridview getview is repeat

Tags: android, gridview

How to fix with  `Gridview` getview  position Too little cause repetitive problems

it is my code

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private  ArrayList<UserInforData> myData;

    public  MyAdapter(ArrayList<UserInforData> data){
        myData = data;

    }
    public  void updateData(ArrayList<UserInforData> data){
        myData = data;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserInforData  d= myData.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: "+d.getUserPic());
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: "+myData.toString());
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.islivelayout,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.liveImg =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.liveimg);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

//            if(d.isLive==1){
            Log.d(TAG, "isLive: "+d.getUserPic());
            String reSizeUrl = JinShanImageScaleUtil.replaceJinShanUrl(d.getUserPic(),30,30);

            GlideUtil.loadUrl(mActivity, d.getUserPic(), R.drawable.lobby_defult_profile, holder.liveImg, false, false);

//            }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

i try to getPosition is at 5 or 6 
but i sliding will repeat the same picture
please tell how to fix

Answer (score 0):

it seems there's no problem with your code,  check the data , by the way, you have not used reSizeUrl